# Termwise differentiation of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, uniform-convergence

THEOREM 17.5 .2 Termwise Differentiation of Series
Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}(x)$ converge on an $x$ interval $I$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{d x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d x} a_{n}(x)
$$
if the series on the right converges uniformly on $I$. (The theorem is from the book "Engineering Mathematics, M.D. Greenberg 2nd edition, page 875.)

My question is why uniform convergence allows us to have such equality?
Initially I thought distributivity allows such equality needs to hold but I couldn't understand why uniform convergence have such superiority. Also, could you give an example of such series that holds the given equality but not uniformly convergent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @808GroundState  Thanks for the answer I understand now.